# render in routes RESTful routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not exactly sure if I have a clear understanding what rendering means in RESTful routes.

For example:
In my Pages controller,

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    render "home.html.erb"
  end
end
```

on my routes.rb file
i have the following:

```
get "/" => "pages#home"
```

does `render home.html.erb` mean output the info on this page?

Thanks!

Comment: Your render 'home.html.erb' is obsolete. Feel free to delete that line

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `render` does the work of rendering your application’s content for use by a browser when your action is invoked. You don't really need to explicitly specify the name of the view if your view name matches the action name and placed in the right folder in app/views

for eg, if you have your view in `app/views/pages/` , your controller can just be

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end
end
```

And even if you want to render a template which name is different than the action name (or localized in another place); you don't need to specify the file extension, only its name (path/name if outside the scope of the designated folder for the views of your controller)...

Ex, if you have a template `app/views/pages/home_template.html.erb` for your `home` action you could do

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    render 'home_template' 
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation. i just started learning programming recently so I ask a lot of silly questions. if you have any resources you think are helpful for me, please let me know. thanks!